# Writing a Semicolon containing String to CSV with "," as Delimiter still causes Separation in CSV-File

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, delimiter

I want to write strings that include semicolons to CSV.

This is what I have:

```
name = ["Peter;Parker"]
 
file = open("Test.csv", "a", newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(name)
```

So the problem is, I want the complete string name in column 1, but in fact the semicolon splits the part before and after into column 1 and column 2

Comment: Are you seeing this behaviour in a spreadsheet?  Some spreadsheet applications will try a variety of column separators, sometimes configurable while the file is being opened.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes in the spreadsheet, so you are saying the problem isn't on the Python output side, but on the csv file program itself?

Comment: Yes, possibly. Your file seems to be a single column csv, so if the spreadsheet program finds a potential separator inside the column it make assume it's a column separator.  This may be configurable in the import dialog.  For example, here's the import dialog for libreoffice calc: https://imgur.com/a/7zvvTK7

Answer (score 1):

So the comment from @snakecharmerb was correct.
In my case I was trying to open the csv file with Excel and Excel has Semicolon as a default delimiter.

Instead of double clicking the csv file to open Excel you can check if the raw text is correct by editing the file via notepad.
If you want to open it with Excel you need to load an empty excel file and go to Data and import from Text. Now load the csv file and you are asked which delimiter you want to use, no you can unselect semicolon and choose none or just ,